# How do I get usernames of other users in Parse in Android?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

i'm trying to get usernames of other users and i end up getting just username of current user .

[,here's other users in my _User class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAtOo.png)

here's my code,

```
public class UsersListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_list);
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

        final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
        final ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usernames);
        ParseUser user= new ParseUser();
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereNotEqualTo("username",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

        Log.i("usernames",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        query.addAscendingOrder("username");
        
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
           
                if (e == null) {
                    if (objects.size() > 0) {
                        for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                           usernames.add(user.getUsername());
                            Log.i("usernames",user.getUsername());
                        }
                        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    }
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("usernames","hi");an
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

when i removed this line:  "query.whereNotEqualTo("username",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());" ,i got the current user username .
and i got no errors in logcat :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: as i mentioned before ,i'm trying to get users usernames and show them up in my listView as friendlist for my current user ,but i'm just getting username of my current user instead of other users usernames , idk if the problem is about access to others users or is just about query here :
<query.whereNotEqualTo("username",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());>

Answer (score 0):

The line query.whereNotEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername()); is filtering out the current user from the query results, which is why you are only getting the current user's username in the list.

If you want to retrieve the usernames of all users except the current user, you should remove this line:

```
public class UsersListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_list);
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

        final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
        final ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usernames);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.addAscendingOrder("username");

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (objects.size() > 0) {
                        for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                            // Exclude the current user's username
                            if (!user.getUsername().equals(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername())) {
                                usernames.add(user.getUsername());
                            }
                        }
                        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    }
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("usernames", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This modified code will populate the usernames list with usernames of all users except the current user and display them in the ListView. Make sure to remove the line that was excluding the current user's username from the query filter, as shown above.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,i tried ur code below , and i did get "Salim" in my list view while my current user is "James", so the other user username it doesnt show up ,but i've made progress

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
i found the soulution which is about the access to others users, i set the ACL manually to public to all the users :

[image of Users ACL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K1fs.png)

-and copy paste the update code of **@Sarah** ,and got my list view full of all the users usernames.

-the probleme it was give the current user access to other users.

> i hope this help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful about your App security when dealing with user class data.
In fact, making the User class publicly accessible will expose your app to serious security threats.

I recommend to follow one of the subsequent solutions:

**- solution 1:** It is recommended to be sure that the requester user has the sufficient permissions to get the user List. For instance, he should belong to admin role.

--step 1: You need to add the admin user to the "admin" role either by code or directly from the parse dashboard:

[image]

--step 2: add the following function to your cloud code functions:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("ListUsers", function(request, response) {  
  var adminRoleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
  adminRoleQuery.equalTo('name', 'admin');
  adminRoleQuery.equalTo('users', request.user);    
    adminRoleQuery.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then(async function(adminRole) {
      if (!adminRole) {
        response.error(' Users Could only be listed by an admin:');
      }
      else{
          const User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
          const query = new Parse.Query(User);
          var usersList = await query.find({useMasterKey: true});

          if(usersList ==null)
          {
            response.error("There is an error when retrieving the user");
          }
          else
          {
            response.success(usersList);
          }
      }
    });     
});
```

--step 3: From your Android App, call the cloud code function using the following code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
//        params.put("userEmail", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("ListUsers", params, new Function2<List<ParseUser>, ParseException>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> usersList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "****Retrieved users: " + usersList.size());
            findViewById(R.id.tvInfo).setText("users:" + usersList.size());
            findViewById(R.id.tvInfo).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (ParseUser user : usersList) {
                Log.d(TAG, "****Retrieved user " +
                        user.get("email").toString() + " "
                );
                Log.d(TAG, "****Retrieved user " +
                        user.get("name").toString() + " " +
                        user.get("department").toString() + " " +
                        user.get("email").toString() + " " +
                        user.get("phoneNumber").toString()
                );
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "****Error occured when calling the cloud code function (ListUsers): " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

**- solution 2:** But, if the user List should be accessible by every one, at least, put the logic retrieving the user list in a cloud code function, so that, you have the ability to perform additional control on the data that will be publicly exposed. For instance, if you need to just expose the username and its email, just modify your cloud code function to:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("ListUsers", function(request, response) {
  

  const User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
          const query = new Parse.Query(User);
          query.select("username", "email");

          query.find({useMasterKey: true}).then(async function(usersList) {
            if(usersList ==null)
            {
              response.error("There is an error when retrieving the user list");
            }
            else
            {
              response.success(usersList);
            }
          });

});
```

This cloud code function could be called with the same Android code of the previous solution (step 3 of the first solution).